# Setting ContentType causing multiple requests in MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, http

I have a simple GetFile Method in a Web API that returns a file stored as binary in a database. The file can be either image, video or a recording, so I set the content type based on the extension:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(Guid Id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var file = db.Files.Where<NonConformityFile>(item => item.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault<NonConformityFile>();

        byte[] imgData = file.FileContents;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);

        if (file.FileExtension == "png")
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        else if (file.FileExtension == "mp4")
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4");
        else if (file.FileExtension == "caf")
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/x-caf");
        else
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, file.FileExtension + " is not a supported file format"));

        return response;
    }
```

This Works fine, but when adding some Security to the Method (by providing a token in the http header) it started crashing. When setting a breakpoint, I discovered that the breakpoint was actually hit twice. And the second time the token was gone from the header, causing authentication failure.

Further debugging made me find out that setting the response.Content.Header.ContentType causes the GetFile Method to be called a second time.

Is this designed behaviour, or some crazy side effects from something in my Development environment?

To reproduce, try this:

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream());
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

        return response;
    }
```

And see if the Method is run twice. I cannot see the Logic in this behaviour, and it is causing problems in my authentication.

Comment: Further investigation indicates that it might actually be a problem With the Postman REST Client. When replaying the requests in Fiddler and Advanced Rest Client, I didnt get the problem. Which is a shame, because Postman is the best REST Client in my opinion...